# Accommodation in Rancagua, Chile for less than 30 USD/night?

Tags: accommodation, chile

I'm looking for conventional (not Airbnb, couch surfing, etc) accommodation in the Chilean town of Rancagua, for one person, for under 30 USD per night. Who knows any?

Comment: Hostels acceptable?

Comment: Absolutely. I was looking for something that could be booked straightaway.

Comment: $35 a night I can find...

Comment: Exactly. Airbnb is a bit cheaper, but nothing that's conventional. At least, not which can be found online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently (last month) stayed for a few nights at [Hostal Estado](https://www.facebook.com/hostalestado565) (on the pedestrian section of Estado between Gamero and O'Carroll), cellphone: [82514972](http://www.buscarancagua.cl/hostales/hostal-estado-cecilia) for a few nights for 10000clp/night, just me in a tiny room with shared bathroom (bring your own toilet paper), but it was centrally-located and had good wifi.  (I had a feeling, though, that it might have been a discounted rated and that she usually charges more, though throws in a meal for those paying more).  I was also quoted 12000clp/night at [Hospedaje el Cobre](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRBwhtOAhbQ) (hostalelcobre@hotmail.com) at Freire 1050 (right across from the stadium), though I was inquiring for longish-term (so YMMV).  The owner of that place said she had another place in town that started at 15000clp/night.  Most of the other "hostales" (not really related to the youth hostel concept) seemed to be starting at 25000clp/night for a single.

If your stay was longer-term (like a week or more), you might be able to get a cheap stay at a "pensión", but they are usually more geared towards miners who come to Rancagua to work temporarily, or students who would never think to do something like drink or party.  I saw several *pensiones* on Ibieta, as well as other places around the *centro* and near the Terminal O'Higgins (though the one I think called Magdalenda near the bus station also started at 25000/night short-term, IIRC).  Some *pensiones* were also advertising on http://yapo.cl.

Comment: Are you able to provide one direct link to any of the places you mention?

Comment: Apparently I am: https://www.facebook.com/hostalestado565 though I am honestly kinda surprised the FB page even exists. I don't know if they answer messages sent to the account (maybe I'm just cynical). She did call me back when I called her one day from the number at http://www.buscarancagua.cl/hostales/hostal-estado-cecilia

Answer (score 1):

On [Booking.com](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?sid=1746f0bab2aeb7de21cc3d1ecc5e5772;dcid=1;checkin=2015-09-11;checkout=2015-09-12;city=-898706;class_interval=1;csflt=%7B%7D;dcsc=1;dtdisc=0;hlrd=0;hyb_red=0;inac=0;label_click=undef;nha_red=0;no_rooms=1;redirected_from_city=0;redirected_from_landmark=0;redirected_from_region=0;review_score_group=empty;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;ss_all=0;ssb=empty;sshis=0&;order=price;track_sr_ajax_click=1) the cheapest rooms go for 42`USD`, even if booking several months in advance.

On [Hostelworld.com](http://www.hostelworld.com/) no accommodation is listen for Rancagua.

On [Expedia.com](https://www.expedia.com/Hotel-Search?#destination=Rancagua,%20Chile&startDate=10/06/2015&endDate=10/07/2015&adults=1&regionId=6085078&sort=price&view=results) only Santiago accommodation is listed.

Therefore I would say that no conventional accommodation is available in Rancagua for less than 30`USD`.

Comment: Thanks. But, I would say, based on your research, there is no conventional accommodation that can be booked online for under 30 USD. But, in fact, I've found Hotel Rio Rancagua sometimes has online bookable rooms for 27 USD per night. However, as budget accommodation in Chile tends to be closer to 20 USD per night, I suspect there are hotels in Rancagua that can not be booked online.

Comment: @MastaBaba why not post the location of the hotel/hostel where you ended up staying? :)

Comment: I didn't. I skipped town and went to Santiago. I'll add an answer.

Comment: _I suspect there are hotels in Rancagua that can not be booked online_ ... there are tons of multi-decade multi-location businesses here whose mere address can't seem to be found anywhere online. \*facepalm\*

Answer (score 1):

Booking.com currently lists three hotels under 30USD (excluding VAT) when entering dates sufficiently far in the future. The cheapest comes in at 25USD for a single room, excluding VAT, at 19%, meaning there's currently one hotel ([Hospedaje Angelica](http://www.booking.com/hotel/cl/hospedaje-angelica.html)) available for under 30USD per night.